# Is there a way to allocate a namespace dynamically to a c# soap service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm working on a c# soap service that is to replace an existing legacy service, but should accept the same requests.
As it turns out, the namespace is different per environment, so the messages we receive on the service will have one namespace for UAT, but a different one for live. No idea why it was done this way, as it is a legacy service and the original programmers are long gone!

Ideally to simplify deployment, I'd like to be able to have namespace as part of the config, so this would be set automatically.

I know that namespace has nothing to do with the location of the service etc., I'm just trying to get it to fit in with what was done previously before I turned up! Essentially, what I'm after is the equivalent of:

```
[WebService(Namespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NamespaceValue"])]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class MySoapService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{   
    [WebMethod]
    public async Task<XmlDocument> SomeMethod(XmlDocument objDocument)
    {
```

However, the Namespace appears to require a constant for this.  The legacy version had to have the namespace changed and the code recompiled before deploying to the appropriate environment.  Is there a simple way to set the namespace dynamically, or do I have no choice but to get our client to update their requests to have a consistent namespace regardless of environment?  I was hoping to just get it to fit in seamlessly.

Comment: Have a different configuration file.  The namespaace is in the configuration file

Comment: @jdweng That was the idea.  The issue is that the bit of code I posted won't work because it objects to a literal namespace being substituted with a variable.

Comment: The code needs : [XmlRoot(Namespace="URL")]. You are probably in the configuration have just the URL.